# Node.js data transfer

Tags: php, node.js, data-transfer

I am transferring data from node to PHP. I am using same url to transfer data and may require to call it for more than 10 times in a loop, but it only accepts 5 times. The next 5 will be error (parse error). How to fix it?

code

```
function win_settings_fn(noos)
    {


                     var str="";
                     var len = str.length ;
                     win_settings.headers = {'Content-length' : len, 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}     

                     var request = http.request(win_settings, function (response) {
                     response.on('data', function (data) {


                        var response= JSON.parse(data);

                        console.log(str+"respose   ..........."+noos);


                     });

                     response.on('error', function (err) {

                     });

                     response.on('end', function () {

                                       });
                       });


                     request.on('error', function (err) {

                        console.log("failed.............."+noos);

                     });
                     request.write(str +"\0");
                     request.end();

              }
```

This is the code am using.

if I call

```
win_settings_fn(1)
win_settings_fn(2)
win_settings_fn(3)
win_settings_fn(4)
win_settings_fn(5)
win_settings_fn(6)
win_settings_fn(7)
win_settings_fn(8)
win_settings_fn(9)
win_settings_fn(10)
```

The result is

```
respose   ...........1
respose   ...........2
respose   ...........3
respose   ...........4
respose   ...........5
failed..............6
failed..............7
failed..............8
failed..............9
respose   ...........10
```

Why is it so? Is there any issue with sending the data?

Comment: I don't know. Do you have code?

Comment: You might check your php config for max clients or listen backlog settings. Although parse error seems odd.

Comment: listen backlog settings? how ? am not sure about that